# Hidden data in excel

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-2007, vba

I would like to know how can we get the hidden data about the excel workbook programmatically e.g. which cell value is hidden, hidden row, hidden column, hidden sheet etc etc? how this data is stored in filesystem?

can this data or metadata be changed externally?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617000/finding-hidden-sheets-and-hidden-cells-in-excel-with-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question...hence my comment.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff956189%28v=office.14%29.aspx) sheds some light on how to retrieve a list of hidden rows and columns using `XML`. (It also sheds some light on how Excel stores this information.)

Perhaps this will point you in the right direction.